# For Kasiski Test,How to implement 26x26 table in Python

Tags: python, vigenere

Here is the table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vigen%C3%A8re_square_shading.svg

How can I implement this table in Python? What is the way(s) for this?

And any clue about how can I check for example Row: L & Column G becomes R welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use the standard library where possible to avoid rolling my own code and inadvertently leaving things out (like accidentally misplacing or forgetting a letter.)

```
import string
import collections

def vigsquare(printable=False):
    '''
    Returns a string like a vigenere square,
    printable joins each row with a newline so it's literally square
    printable=False (defaul) joins without newlines for easier 
    searching by row and column index
    '''
    alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
    rotater = collections.deque(alpha)
    vigsquare_list = []
    for i in xrange(26):
        vigsquare_list.append(''.join(rotater))
        rotater.rotate(-1)
    if printable:
        return '\n'.join(vigsquare_list) 
    else:
        return ''.join(vigsquare_list)
```

and

```
def vigenere(row, column):
    ''' 
    Return a character from a vigenere square by 
    row and column letter.
    vigenere('L', 'G') returns 'R'
    '''
    alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
    rowindex = alpha.find(row)
    columnindex = alpha.find(column)
    return vigsquare()[rowindex*26 + columnindex]

print vigsquare(printable=True)
vigenere('L', 'G')
```

gives you:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJK
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
PQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
STUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
TUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
VWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
YZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
```

and

```
'R'
```

There was another solution that looked interesting here, but I didn't trust it because I didn't understand it, so I'll unittest my code and the other code to see if it's reliable.

```
def vig_2(row, col):
    return string.ascii_uppercase[(ord(row) + ord(col)) % 26]
```

And unittested comparing both approaches. The second one (borrowed from NPE, to whom I now owe an upvote) is likely to be more performant if it is correct.:

```
import unittest
class VigTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_vigenere(self):
        self.assertEqual(vigenere('L', 'G'), 'R')
    def test_vigsquare(self):
        self.assertEqual(vigsquare(printable=False), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY')
    def test_vig2(self):
        for i in string.ascii_uppercase:
            for j in string.ascii_uppercase:
                self.assertEqual(vig_2(i, j), vigenere(i, j))

unittest.main()
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.038s

OK
```

So it looks like NPE had a very good solution!

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Comments are very helpful, since i am also trying to learn python, those ones explains good. +rep :)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> mat = [(letters * 2)[i:i+26] for i in range(26)]
>>> print '\n'.join(mat)
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJK
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
PQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
STUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
TUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
VWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
YZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
```

Alternatively, you could just compute the element on the fly:

```
def get_elem(row, col):
  return 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'[(ord(row) + ord(col)) % 26]

print get_elem('L', 'G')
```

Comment: Ok,thats one way, but i need it static in the program. Because i need to make dynamic comparisons.
E.g in my program i am going to check Row L & Column G = becomes R